# There are some problems when using Sqlalchemy to query the data between time1 and time2

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

My database is SQL Server 2008.

The type of time character I want to query in the database (such as finishdate) is datetime2

I just want data between "10-11" and "10-17".
When using Sqlalchemy, I use

```
cast(FinishDate, DATE).between(cast(time1, DATE),cast(time2, DATE))
```

to query dates, but it does not return any data (**I confirm that there must be some data statements meet the query time range**)

==============================================

```
from sqlalchemy import DATE


bb = "2021-10-11 12:21:23"  
cc = "2021-10-17 16:12:34"  
record = session.query(sa.Name cast(sa.FinishDate, DATE)).filter(
                cast(sa.SamplingTime, DATE).between(cast(bb, DATE), cast(cc, DATE)),
                sa.SamplingType != 0
            ).all()
```

or

```
record = session.query(sa.Name cast(sa.FinishDate, DATE)).filter(
                cast(sa.SamplingTime, DATE)>= cast(bb, DATE),
                sa.SamplingType != 0
            ).all()
```

**Both return []**

Something is wrong with my code and I don't know what the trouble is.

Comment: Have you tried starting with `bb` and `cc` as Python [datetime.date](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) or [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) objects?

Comment: Yup, try removing the `cast` calls after doing that too, could be affecting the comparison.

Comment: But my input data doesn't support this writing method.

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me, I only changed the DATE that you are using to Date

```
from sqlalchemy import Date
record = session.query(
    sa.Name cast(sa.FinishDate, Date)
 ).filter(
    cast(sa.SamplingTime, Date).between(
        cast(bb, Date), cast(cc, Date)
    ),
    sa.SamplingType != 0
 ).all()
```

As a matter of fact first parameter of cast can be a string also, so in this case its fine to pass date as string in cast.

```
:param expression: A SQL expression, such as a
         :class:`_expression.ColumnElement`
         expression or a Python string which will be coerced into a bound
         literal value.
```

Comment: I am so appreciate your explanation!

Comment: As you said,it doesn't work for me.@Anand Tripathi

Comment: Weird it should work and it worked for me as well. can you check the date that is in bb and cc and other variables or can you just print(record) query without .all() it will print the query in raw format